# how to make multi value variable in addon development

Tags: templates, add-on, add-on-development

I am developing an addon for EE.
i could not find a way to make a variable with multi value behavior.
like: 
i would like to write in the template:
{location:lat}
{location:lng}
this can be (Pair Variables) but it is always about loops.

what is the proper and the write Array syntax to parse to get what i want in the template.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only add-ons which have an official method of using variable modifiers are fieldtypes, where your fieldtype class' `replace_tag` function controls `{my_field}`, `replace_lat` controls `{myfield:lat}`, etc.

If you want to use the modifier sytax in a plugin or module, you'd simply name your variables `location:lat` and `location:lng` in the array you pass to `ee()->TMPL->parse_variables()`.

The standard way of accessing nested variables like this, given a variables array that looks like:

```
array(
    array(
        'location' => array(
            'lat' => 'foo',
            'lng' => 'bar'
        )
    )
);
```

... would be:

```
{location}
    {lat}
    {lng}
{/location}
```

Comment: Thanks allot, Derek when I do the same thing I got the result as Array.
it reads it as an array.

it works for me as : 
`$json['location'] = array(
   array('lat'=>$json['location']['lat'],'lng'=>$json['location']['lng'])
  );`